# How can I parse an xml-serialized List<int> in a stored procedure via OPENXML?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, openxml

I am serializing a list of integers as follows:

```
List<int> Ids=new List<int>();
Ids.Add(3);
Ids.Add(98);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<int>));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
xs.Serialize(ms,Ids);

string resultXML = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

and passing `resultXML` to a stored procedure;

The xml (`resultXML`) is of the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<int>3</int>
</ArrayOfInt>
```

I am trying to parse this in my stored procedure as follows:

```
insert into Table(did,pid)
(SELECT 1, id
FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, '/ArrayOfInt/int',)
        WITH (id int
              ))
```

But I'm not getting the values; the `id` column is always `null`:

```
            id
----------- -----------
1           NULL
```

How can I fix this? I can change any of the SP/TSQL, the xml, and the C#/.NET code.

Comment: unless its a typo you seem to be seriaising ProjectGroupIds not Ids

Comment: It is unclear what the question is here, but if anything it seems that the question is really "how do I parse/deserialize this xml in TSQL", and not so much to do with any of "serialization", "`List<int>`", or "C#"... can you clarify?

Comment: typo .. meant to change the actual list name ..

Comment: if c# can help me crate an XML that looks like :

Comment: < ?xml version="1.0"?>
     < ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
< int id="3" />
< / ArrayOfInt>

Comment: @user1262278 like what? you already said that is what `resultXML` **is**... so what is it you want different?

Comment: the sp isn't able to read ids
<int >3 </int>
needs to be
<int id="3" />

Comment: @user1262278 there is no need to insert spaces into the xml here; instead, use a back-tick to wrap the sections that are xml - then `<xml><is fine="here"/></xml>`

Comment: I took a stab at rephrasing the question to more accurately represent your intent: did I get it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're just missing a `.`:

```
SELECT 1, id
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/ArrayOfInt/int')
WITH (id int '.')
```

With result:

```
            id
----------- -----------
1           3

(1 row(s) affected)
```

(adding additional `<int>42</int>` etc values results in additional rows etc, as you would expect)

Comment: @user1262278 note: in some cases you may want to use `text()` instead of `.` - not sure; just to keep in mind, really

Comment: @user1262278 `.` just means "the context node"; if you don't specify a 3rd expression, it assumes you mean "an attribute with the same name as the column", so it is looking for `@id` on the `<int>`, i.e. `<int id="42">3</int>` would produce `42` for `WITH (id int)`